# No sound in my Dell laptop

Tags: windows-7, drivers, audio, dell-vostro

I upgraded the operating system in my `Dell Vostro 1400` laptop a day ago from Windows XP to Windows 7. Since then I have had no sound in my laptop. I have tried to troubleshoot and no problem has been detected. Under the 'Device Manager' external speakers are set as the default sound device and there are no other options provided. Anyone with a solution to this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to device properties > Details tab > Hardware ID from dropdown menu. Copy and paste this string into a device driver repository such as devid.info

If you cannot find a compatible driver try this solution posted on Dell forum:

```
After Installing Windows 7 on your Dell vostro 1400

Go to the Device Manager and uninstall existing sound driver
Install Registry File
Install Downloaded Sound Driver (SIGMATEL STAC 92XX C-Major HD Audio)
Restart Your Dell vostro 1400

For Sound Driver http://downloads.dell.com/audio/R171786.exe
```

http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3517/p/19459632/20153852.aspx#20153852

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike. Option 2 worked, I now have my laptop sound back! Problem solved.

Comment: Great, kindly mark the question as answered if the solution worked for you.